# how to fix a binding that violates logical tree rules

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

```
InvalidOperationException: Specified element is already 
the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
```

Googling this error has so far given me just enough to suspect that the bindings I'm using violates the rule that a child element can have only one parent, either visually or logically. I also *think* that the offending property is where I try to bind the Content of the button to an Image.

If there is only one button in the stack panel using these bindings, it works. But more than one button does not.

I don't really see why this does violate the one-parent rule, or know how to fix it. Can someone evolve my binding to one that works?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Base Binding in a Resource Dictionary

```
<Style x:Key="BoundImageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{Binding SmallImage}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipTitle}" />
</Style>
```

## Binding in the View

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel.Resources >
            <sys:Double x:Key="btnSize">24</sys:Double>
            <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BoundImageButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource btnSize}" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource btnSize}" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" DataContext="{Binding AddItemControl}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" DataContext="{Binding EditItemControl}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}" DataContext="{Binding DeleteItemControl}" />

    </StackPanel>
```

## Binding Source example in the ViewModel

```
    public ButtonData AddItemControl
    {
        get
        {
            return _addItemControl ??
            (_addItemControl = new ButtonData
            {
                ToolTipTitle = _crudTextConverter.AddNew(this),
                SmallImage =
                    "pack://application:,,,/Smack.Core.Presentation.Wpf;component/Images/simplicio_add.png",
                Command = AddItemCommand,
            });
        }
    }
    private ButtonData _addItemControl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only creates *one* `Image` for all controls the style is applied to:

```
<Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Source="{Binding SmallImage}" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You could externalize the image and make it [non-shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx):

```
<!-- In some compiled Resources dictionary that is accessible from the style -->
<Image x:Key="image" x:Shared="false"
       Source="{Binding SmallImage}" />
```

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource image}"/>
```

---

Alternatively you can set the `ContentTemplate` instead, all buttons have the same template instance but the ui-elements are created from it independently:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding SmallImage}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: I want to use the last option but the image is not showing up. I replaced the Content binding with the template, and there is no data binding error but no image either. Must I use a ContentPresenter somewhere? What am I missing now?

Comment: @Berryl: The `ContentTemplate` templates the `Content`, so you need to set that to the data object which contains the property `SmallImage`, presumably that object is the `DataContext` so try adding a setter like this: `<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>`